# Why don't athletes who don't want their autographs resold draw a shape to designate it's not for resale?

Tags: baseball

Why don't athletes who don't want their autographs resold draw a shape to designate it's not for resale?

On their website they list what the shape is and then perhaps an independent authenticator would display them for all athletes.

Here's an example, a Trump signed ball with a dollar sign added.

If this got listed on eBay, Craigslist or such they'd have to remove it.

[image]

Comment: "If this got listed on eBay, Craigslist or such they'd have to remove it." This is not obvious to me. Could you provide a reference which shows that it is legally possible to restrict resale in this way? The principle of first sale seems relevant here.

Comment: Why would athletes not want their autographs to be resold?

Comment: @PhilipKendall  Yes https://www.ebay.com/help/selling/listings/creating-managing-listings/removed-listings?id=4656. "To make sure eBay is a safe place to buy and sell, sometimes we have to remove listings. We'll only remove a listing for one of the following reasons:

It violates one of our policies
It violates a law
The rights owner of the item requested it be removed
It's been active on the site for a year or more without any sales"

Comment: @Ginge Because if they were provided a a personal memento then they were not intended to be resold.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's predicated on a specific interpretation of copyright law which is not obvious. The copyright question is interesting but not one for Sports SE.

Comment: @PhilipKendall (Nothing is being copied.)

Comment: Copyright law does not just apply to literal direct copying of things.

Comment: @Nij Yes. "Copyright law grants authors and artists the exclusive right to make and sell copies of their works, the right to create derivative works, and the right to perform or display their works publicly.":

Point being?

Comment: You said "nothing is being copied" as if it refutes the notion that copyright law is important here, when it's the (absence of) copying itself that is totally irrelevant to whether copyright law allows such a condition as you proposed.

Comment: I don't follow. Sorry. I don't have the brain power.

Answer (score 1):

They don't do this because it would have absolutely no legal effect, and neither the item's owner nor a marketplace provider would have any obligation to remove it from sale.

This is a long-established principle, for example enshrined in the United States of America as the first-sale doctrine, in the European Union by a [range of (less absolute) directives and precedent](http://www.cearta.ie/2016/10/exhausting-exhaustion-the-limits-of-the-first-sale-doctrine-in-eu-copyright-law/), and in other jurisdictions under similar regulations.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure the first sale doctrine applies here. While I agree the situation seems closer to *UMG vs. Augusto* than *Vernor vs. Autodesk*, do you have anything you can cite to support this?

Comment: "People are allowed to sell their own property" is a long-standing common law precedent, and often transferred to civil law as well, but finding references that broadly show this wasn't easy enough at the time.

Comment: "To make sure eBay is a safe place to buy and sell, sometimes we have to remove listings. We'll only remove a listing for one of the following reasons:

It violates one of our policies
It violates a law
The rights owner of the item requested it be removed
It's been active on the site for a year or more without any sales"

You would seem to be saying that a seller can't dictate how something purchased is to be used?  That's like saying if I buy a song I can re publish it because it's now mine.

Comment: First-sale doctrine refers to "U.S. copyright and trademark law by limiting certain rights of a copyright or trademark owner".  This does not mean the author cannot specify additional restrictions. For example I sell you a valuable painting because you say you love it. So as part of that I say you're not able to profit from it for X years or you give me 35% of the proceeds if you break that agreement. 

Copyright and trademark are but one set of non-civil? legal mechanisms to protect works.

Comment: Record companies used to punch a hole in the sleeve of demo albums and informed the stores they were not-for-resale. Is that not the same practice?

Comment: Pretty much exactly that practice was found to be null and void in *UMG vs Augusto*, so that's not a strong argument.

Comment: There's a whole mess of contract and related law that you're mixing up, @RandyZeitman, these comments really aren't the place to sort them out. Go read the contract tag on Law SE, for example, where much of your misunderstanding has been covered by some reasonably expert users in good depth.

Comment: It's a mess? Why is it not simple. And indeed why is there any discussion about the law for this question. Certainly not by me. My sole question is why don't athletes designate what items they allow for resale or not. Is there some possible reason a person can't designate conditions for something they give or sell? Does that require legal inquiry? It seems utterly basic.

Comment: Because the law doesn't say they can, or the law explicitly says they can't, unless it does, until it doesn't, depending on where you are and when it happens and who does what in each. If you have to ask why the law is relevant and don't see why it's not simple at all, that's the entire problem. So go and read what experts can say and why.